# How to get rid of warning using withUnsafeBytes() and outputStream.write() in Swift 5.0

Tags: swift, deprecated, outputstream

I have the following function below and I am unable to get rid of the compile warning.
Warning =    'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead

I tried the online doc about withUnsafeBytes (including stackoverflow.com) but the poor documentation of withUnsafeBytes() mixed with the unusual function outputStream.write (which requires an UnsafePointer) made me unable to understand how the pointer must be passed nor what $0 refers to.  I know $0 is an implicit parameter of the code closure but the code I got does not explicitly list the closure parameters and I am unable to figure out what $0 is.

```
func sendMessage(message: String)
{
    // URL Encode the message
    let URLEncodedMem = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: message.utf8CString.count * 3 + 1)
    defer { URLEncodedMem.deallocate() }
    urlEncode( URLEncodedMem, message )
    let urlEncodedMsg = String( cString: URLEncodedMem )

    // Build the server message to send
    let strToSend = "GET /userInput.mtml?userInput=\(urlEncodedMsg) HTTP/1.1\r\n"
            +       "Host: \(hostName):\(hostPort)\r\n\r\n"
    let data = strToSend.data(using: .utf8)!

    _ = data.withUnsafeBytes { outputStream.write($0, maxLength: data.count) }  // Warning = 'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead
}   //  sendMessage
```

I would like the code to continue to work hopefully even when Swift makes other changes with withUnsafeBytes.

I suspect perhaps the problem is that withUsafeBytes> is not supported??  Not sure??

Answer (score 1):

This will compile without errors in Swift 5.

```
let strToSend = "GET /userInput.mtml?userInput=\(urlEncodedMsg) HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    +       "Host: \(hostName):\(hostPort)\r\n\r\n"
let data = strToSend.data(using: .utf8)!

_ = data.withUnsafeBytes { outputStream.write($0.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self).baseAddress!, maxLength: data.count) }
```

(You can find some articles about the deprecation of old `withUnsafeBytes` in SO.)

But in your case, you can simply write it as:

```
let strToSend = "GET /userInput.mtml?userInput=\(urlEncodedMsg) HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    +       "Host: \(hostName):\(hostPort)\r\n\r\n"

outputStream.write(strToSend, maxLength: strToSend.utf8.count)
```